# Getting error while running a below program in python

Tags: python, syntax

Getting error while running a below program in python

```
data = read_data()
batsman_name = first_batsman(data)
def first_batsman(data=data):
    innings = data['innings'][0]
first_innings = innings['1st innings']
deliveries = first_innings['deliveries']
first_ball =(deliveries[0] [0.1])
first_batsman = first_ball['batsman']
    return(first_batsman)
print(first_batsman)
```

getting error as :

> return(first_batsman)
>   ^
>   IndentationError: unexpected indent

I even tried below program :

```
data = read_data()
batsman_name = first_batsman(data)
def first_batsman(data=data):
    innings = data['innings'][0]
first_innings = innings['1st innings']
deliveries = first_innings['deliveries']
first_ball =(deliveries[0] [0.1])
first_batsman = first_ball['batsman']
return(first_batsman)
print(first_batsman)
```

But still getting error as :

> return(first_batsman)
>   SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

What is the solution for this?

Comment: The solution is to use `return` only inside a function (and to make sure that it is indented properly, with respect to the scope it is located in).

Comment: Everything that you want inside your `first_batsman()` function must be indented, and that includes the `return()`. So `first_innings = ...` signals to Python the end of the function is above it, as it is not indented.

Comment: @Harsha what are you talking about? you can return a value from anywhere as long as you are in a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missunderstood intentations: [may read this](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_blocks.php)

To your code, you may want to try something like this:

```
class First_Batsman( object ) :
    def __init__( self ):
        self.innings = data['innings'][0]
        self.first_innings = innings['1st innings']
        self.deliveries = first_innings['deliveries']
        self.first_ball = deliveries[0][0.1]
        self.first_batsman = first_ball['batsman']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.innings,self.first_innings,self.deliveries,
                   self.first_ball,self.first_batsman)

data = read_data()
batsman_name = first_batsman( data )
print( first_batsman )
```